# Firebase: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using delphi to build my ios App. Starting with firebase 9, I cannot anymore compile my project with firebase. when I try (with -ObjC linker flag) i receive error like:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'
  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      Error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRHeartbeatController", referenced from:      objc-class-ref in ios-arm64/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(FIRHeartbeatLogger.o);
```

and this still firebase 10.2.0. but with firebase 8.15.0 it's was working fine. Is there any change made in firebase 9.0.0 that can explain this? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this github issues page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9822) this issue is similar to what you're facing. You may need to add `FirebaseCoreInternal.xcframework` into your project.